# How to specify inputs on command line

Tags: filebeat

One can specify filebeat input with this config:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  paths:
  - /path/to/dir/*
```

I tried doing same on command line:

```
$ filebeat run -E filebeat.inputs=[{type=log,paths=['/path/to/dir/*']}]
Exiting: Error reading config file: required 'object', but found 'string' in field 'filebeat.inputs.0' (source:'command line flag')
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 issues:

- The `-E` argument needs to be quoted
- The `=` chars need to be `:`

Here goes:

```
filebeat -E "filebeat.inputs=[{type:log,paths:['/path/to/dir/*']}]"
```

Note that `run` is not needed.